# how to handle 'QuerySplittingBehavior' warning

Tags: entity-framework

I am using below query to get the count of Subjects which are active.

Domain Entity has StudentId as foreign key. Also, Domain entity has multiple Subjects with (1 to many)

```
_context.Domain.Where(p=>p.StudentId==request.Id).Include(t=>t.Subjects.Where(x=>x.Active==0)).CountAsync();
```

Query is working fine. However I get below warning.

`Compiling a query which loads related collections for more than one collection navigation, either via 'Include' or through projection, but no 'QuerySplittingBehavior' has been configured. By default, Entity Framework will use`

`'QuerySplittingBehavior.SingleQuery', which can potentially result in slow query performance. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2134277 for more information. To identify the query that's triggering this warning call 'ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Throw(RelationalEventId.MultipleCollectionIncludeWarning))'.`

Is there a better way to query the same?

Comment: You are counting Domain, so there is no need at all to use Include. If you only want to count domains which have an active subject: `var count = await _context.Domain.Where(p=>p.StudentId==request.Id && p.Subjects.Any(s => s.Active)).CountAsync();` Don't forget to await any async method, especially against the DbContext..

Comment: Thanks....actually, I want to count Active Subjects. Basically, "count of active(0) subjects for all programs where program.studentid = request.id  and program.id = target.programid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projection will help with this scenario and help avoid situations with Cartesian Products in the results. If you want to select Domains along with a count of subjects:

```
var domains = await _context.Domain
    .Where(p => p.StudentId == request.Id)
    .Select(p => new DomainDto
    {
        // Copy fields from Domain entity to DTO...
        ActiveSubjectCount = p.Subjects.Where(s => s.Active).Count()
    }).ToListAsync();
```

When reading lists of entity graphs, I recommend creating DTO or view model classes that represent just the information the consumer needs rather than loading large graphs of related entities. This saves on memory and bandwidth when it comes to sending data, and builds more efficient queries that can avoid Cartesian scenarios. Loading an entity graph (root element with it's children/references) would be reserved for when you want to load singular aggregate roots, or at least a much smaller sample size.

If you want to get a Domain object and only return the subjects that are active, EF Core supports filtering child collections:

```
var domains = await _context.Domain
    .Where(p => p.StudentId == request.Id)
    .Include(p => p.Subjects.Where(s => s.Active))
    .ToListAsync();
```

This would load the Domains for a given student and only load the Subjects that are active into the domain.Subjects collection.

If you are using a soft-delete system where most tables are using an "Active" flag of `false` rather than deleting a row, then you can also configure the DbContext to respect that Active flag across the entities so that queries to load data automatically ignore any rows where Active is `false`. This would mean that:

```
var domains = await _context.Domain
    .Where(p => p.StudentId == request.Id)
    .Include(p => p.Subjects)
    .ToListAsync();
```

... would automatically only include active Subjects. The downside of setting up the DbContext with a soft delete flag is that I believe you need to explicitly turn that behaviour off if you want to read Inactive rows. (Such as for auditing or being able to "undelete" data)

Where EF will warn about Cartesians and recommend using split queries is where you have one or more `Include` for collection types while performing a `ToList` or similar operation denoting you want multiple rows. When EF encounters an `Include` it composes a query that performs a JOIN between the entities. If the Domain table has 10 rows and 10 columns, and each Domain has on average 10 subjects where subjects have 20 columns, the resulting query would be:

(10 domain rows x 10 subject rows)
and
(10 domain columns x 20 subject columns)

That is, loading 100 rows, and 20,000 total columns.

Using split queries, EF will compose two queries, one to load the domain rows, and one to load the relevant subject rows.

This will load the 10 domain rows, then build a query to load however many subjects are referenced by those 10 domains. 10x10, 100 subjects assuming every domain had 10 subjects. The key difference is in the total columns coming back. The domain query would be 10 rows x 10 columns (100 columns) while the subject query would be 100 rows x 20 columns (2000 columns) The total data size would be 2100 columns vs. the 20,000 from a Join-based query. As you add more relationships, the rate of growth of a Cartesian product is a multiple of the # of rows *and* the # of columns. Using split tables, the growth is additive, not multiplicative.

It is an option available and not really a "one size fits all". The first questions should always be around "am I loading only the data I really need", then looking at whether the resulting joins might be better suited to being split into separate queries. (Which EF can now support behind the scenes)